# How do i code an afk command like dynos afk command

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, discord.py, command

I need help making a afk command for my discord server. When the afk command is triggered, my bot doesn't respond with a reasoning when you ping the person whos afk. Also, when you return from being afk and type, the bot doesn't send a message saying "(user) is no longer afk". Please help me and tell me what im doing wrong and how can i fix this?

afkdict = {}
@bot.command(name = "afk", brief = "Away From Keyboard",
description = "I'll give you the afk status and if someone pings you before you come back, I'll tell "
"them that you are not available. You can add your own afk message!")
async def afk(ctx, message = "They didn't leave a message!"):
global afkdict

```
if ctx.message.author in afkdict:
    afkdict.pop(ctx.message.author)
    await ctx.send('Welcome back! You are no longer afk.')

else:
    afkdict[ctx.message.author] = message
    await ctx.send("You are now afk. Beware of the real world!")
```

I expected this to run a afk command like the one dyno bot has, but instead its a timer. Please help me code an afk command where if someones afk and gets pinged the bot tells them theyre afk with reasoning and when someone comes back from being afk the bot says welcome back

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `on_message` event and check if the message mentions an afk user. While you can use a command to "set" a user AFK

```
afkdict = {}  # somewhere in the code
@bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):

    # some other checks here

    for user, reason in afkdict.items():
        if user in message.mentions:
            if reason is None:
                reason = ""
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user} is AFK", color=0xFF0000, description=reason[:2500])
            await message.reply(embed=embed)

@bot.command("afk")
async def afk(self, ctx: commands.Context, reason=None):
    afkdict[ctx.author] = reason
    await ctx.send("You are now afk. Beware of the real world!")
```

Read more about the `on_message` event: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message

Reading the docs about the `Message` object might also help: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message

Comment: it says  user has no context

Comment: @abekk I changed the code, It should work now

Comment: Its telling me this: Converting to "Context" failed for parameter "ctx".

Comment: Maybe that's because there's `self` in a non-class function.